# sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an empty ViewController on a tabbar controller, The view is loading but It crashed breakpoint stills on main method without any exceptional information only the following message on the GDB

```
sharedlibrary apply-load-rules all
```

Comment: That's a pretty standard output. Do you get any information within the Xcode window, i.e. EXC_BAD_ACCESS or something similar?

Comment: No, Got only this message at the last on GDB.

Comment: Ok, if you type `continue` into the GDB terminal, what does it say?